# Server 2016 Essentials and Sage 300

Tags: windows-server-2016, domaincontroller, sage-erp, sage-300

We have a small business and just bought Server 2016 Essentials to run Sage 300. When trying to install Sage 300, it says : "Unsupported Environment - Sage 300 does not support installing on a DC". That's a problem because Essentials Server must be a domain controller. But then says that some features won't work (features we won't use) and gives me the option to proceed anyway. I proceed, but the it doesn't run : "the server the unable to process the request due to an internal error". So, my question is: Can Sage run on Server 2016 Essentials? If not, can I upgrade Essentials to Standard and NOT use/install a domain? Right now we only use the server as a file share. This is a small office and we just wanted a file server to run Sage.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question within the scope defined for SO. You probably want to try SuperUser or ServerFault instead - most likely the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is that it **is** possible to run Sage 300 on Server 2016 Essentials.

I was able to click by the "unsupported environment" error and it installed just fine. The Sage website has conflicting information on whether it will run or not but we are running it successfully.

The 2nd error was caused by a bug in our version of Sage, in which a service was not starting correctly (it needs to be manually restarted as a work-around).
Once I did that, everything ran perfectly.